# Apache optimization for images or static files

Tags: apache, static-files, http-caching

I have several pages with about 200 images each. When I access them, Apache opens a lot of threads, using more than 1 Gb of RAM. I can see several "httpd" entries on "top" command, each using 0.6% of RAM.

All files are static, small JPG files. I'm using .htaccess for client side caching, but this is not enough since I have several new users each hour, non-cached ones.

My config:

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 200
KeepAliveTimeout 30
StartServers       1
MinSpareServers    2
MaxSpareServers    4
ServerLimit      300
MaxClients       300
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
MaxRequestWorkers 300
```

What is the best way to serve lots of static files, per page, with low memory usage? It's a CentOS 7, Apache 2.4.6, almost in default config, except the directives above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1GB Ram is quite nothing but Apache is depending also a lot about your CPU specs.

I am not sure how many CPU you have but I think the following setting need to be increased to

```
StartServers       5
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers    10
```

Also you can check the loading time using the developer tools in browser where you can check each image how much it takes to load.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but for future users, what might help with this problem is the compression of http responses, so you might want to look into mod_deflate.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: mod_deflate will use more RAM yet, since it's on-fly compression.